# Windows Forms - How to relocate a window object when there are several screens

Tags: c#, winforms, fullscreen

I have two forms, in the main one I put some controls to hide or show a secondary form (`cronoFrame`) according the selected screen. The secondary form has set the property `FormStartPosition` as `Manual`; this form is created only once, the controls to show it and hide it are a combo box and a check box like this:

[image]

I want that according to the selected screen in the combo box, show on it the secondary form when the de check box is selected. The first time it works fine, but if I select another screen, the form is showed in the first selected screen no matter the selection in combo box.

This is the event method for check box:

```
    private void chkMostrarPantallaDiscursante_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chkMostrarPantallaDiscursante.Checked)
        {
            Screen display = displaysDic[cmbDisplays.SelectedItem.ToString()];
            var wa = display.WorkingArea;
            Utilerias.cronoFrame.Left = wa.Left;
            Utilerias.cronoFrame.Top = wa.Top;
            Utilerias.cronoFrame.Width = wa.Width;
            Utilerias.cronoFrame.Height = wa.Height;
            Utilerias.cronoFrame.Show();
        } else
        {
            Utilerias.cronoFrame.Hide();
        }
    }
```

Making several tests, the only way to achieve this is creating a new object of the secondary form every time that check box is selected and disposing the form when it is not selected. But I need the same object, not a new one. Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: Did you check that `FormStartPosition` is not changing?

Comment: @DonBoitnott it never changes =(

Comment: cmbDisplays is the dropdown? Have you bound this to its selected index change event (too)? Maybe create a UpdateScreens() function, dump all of the if/else code into it, and then call UpdateScreens() in both of those event handlers?

Comment: what is `cronoFrame` ?

Comment: @Robert it not changes the logic flow. Calling `cmbDisplays.SelectedItem` you get the current selected item when press the check box component, so it is not necessary to add an event handler for the combo box.

Comment: `Utilerias.cronoFrame`  looks suspicious.  Post code where that gets created and used.

Comment: @LarsTech `Utilerias` is just a class with the static value of my `System.Windows.Forms` object called `cronoFrame` with its respective `{ get; set; }`

Comment: is cmbDisplays.SelectedItem.ToString() returning a key for displaysDic? Should it be .Value instead?

Comment: @Robert That's about code optimization that does not affect the final result, So, if I make that change issue persists.

Comment: It seems to work for me.  Show us your code for populating `displaysDic` and the code for the `Utilerias` class.